# Regex Match in Python for Time Instances

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to identify time instances using Python regex eg "2.30pm", "1.45 am", "3.30" (Provided am/pm is not given).

Following is the regex I wrote:

```
'\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}[\s]?[am,pm]?'
```

Output I am getting:
2.30p

Output I need:
2.30pm

Also, I would like it to capture string such as "2.30 pmo" as just "2.30" instead of "2.30 pm".

Can someone please help me with the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use regex group instead of character class for to match this or that word. character classes `[]` are used to do OR function on single characters, it won't work with group of characters. Use either capturing or non-capturing group with `|` as delimiter inorder to do OR operation on group of chars.

```
r'\b\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\s?(?:[ap]m\b)?'
```

Comment: thanks, it works for the above cases, can you please suggest me a change so that it does not capture "2.30 pmo" as "2:30 pm" but rather as just "2.30"

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. Not getting anything for "2.30pm" or "2.30pmo"

Comment: @Inherited Remove the second `\b`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `re.match('\d{1,2}(\.|:)\d{1,2}[\s]?(am|pm|AM|PM)?', '2:30 AM').group()` pattern. It will extract time pattern from the strings